# How to get content on the right of a card to position under the image using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am having trouble getting the content on the right of an image in a card to the be below the image using bootstrap and CSS. I have tried looking for solutions online and on the bootstrap documentation but I could not find anything that solves my problem. When I go below a certain responsive size I just want to position the AppName, Description and AppDescription below the image. Thanks for the help.

Html Below

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
           <div class="col-auto col-md-6">
               <img src="img/image.jpg" class="img-fluid image" alt="PayCloud App Demo" width="620" height="465">
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <div class="card-block px-2">
                <p class="card-title AppName">AppName</p>
                <p class="card-title Description">Restaurant Payment Service - January 2020</p>
                <p class="card-text AppDescription">App Description.</p>
                <a href="link.html"><span class="button">View Project</span></a>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

CSS Below

```
.AppName{
    font-family: itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro,sans-serif; /* ITC Bold */ 
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 42px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 42px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    opacity: 80%;
}

.Description{
    color: #869FC9;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.AppDescription{
    opacity: 87%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: realist, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;   
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is @media (CSS)
For more please go ahead and read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Comment: I know what a media query is, but i still cant get it to do what i want.

Comment: Make the image width:100%; (within @media ... )and this will end up forcing to what comes next to go under you image...

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Can you please share with everyone what the problem was? Maybe others will be helped out if they get the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing "col" to "col-auto" and also adding "col-md-6" in the class

Code Below

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
           <div class="col-auto col-md-6">
               <img src="img/image.jpg" class="img-fluid image" alt="PayCloud App Demo" width="620" height="465">
           </div>
           <div class="col-auto col-md-6">
             <div class="card-block px-2">
                <p class="card-title AppName">AppName</p>
                <p class="card-title Description">Restaurant Payment Service - January 2020</p>
                <p class="card-text AppDescription">App Description.</p>
                <a href="link.html"><span class="button">View Project</span></a>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has an example of the horizontal card and the image goes on top when it gets to a certain size.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="..." class="card-img" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">AppName</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Restaurant Payment Service - January 2020</p>
        <p class="card-text AppDescription">App Description.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```